# How do I print the elements of a javascript array to the webpage using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, html

I have reviewed several posts here and several websites but cannot find an answer that works and makes sense to me. I am brand new to HTML and javascript. Basically, I am trying to print this to a webpage (not the console):

12 grape

98 kiwi

0 banana

Here is the code I have written, it does not print anything

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>fruit.html</title>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p></p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var fruits = [
                {
                    kind: "grape",
                    color: "red",
                    quantity: 12,
                    id: "0"
                },
                {
                    kind: "kiwi",
                    color: "brown",
                    quantity: 98,
                    id: "1"
                },
                {
                    kind: "banana",
                    color: "yellow",
                    quantity: 0,
                    id: "2"
                }
            ];
            for(var i=0; i<fruits.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById(fruits[i].id).innerHTML = fruits[i].quantity + fruits[i].kind; 
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would really appreciate your help with this :), the easiest most basic solution would be preferred as I am new to this.

Comment: the main problem is that you try to find elements having id = 0, 1 etc. But take a looki at your html code and answer - can you see at least one element of that kind? 'getElementById' finds existing elements, it does not create them.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

Javascript:

```
 var fruits = [
   {
     kind: "grape",
     color: "red",
     quantity: 12,
     id: "0"
   },
   {
     kind: "kiwi",
     color: "brown",
     quantity: 98,
     id: "1"
   },
   {
     kind: "banana",
     color: "yellow",
     quantity: 0,
     id: "2"
   }
 ];

const container = document.getElementById('container')

fruits.forEach(fruit => {
  const p = document.createElement('p')
  p.textContent = `${fruit.quantity} ${fruit.kind}`
  container.appendChild(p)
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/diogocosta/u8w7s49v/2/

Cheers,

Comment: okay, so the issue with this code is that the list is not supposed to have bullet point in this case actually

Comment: You can just change the `ul` for a `p` tag. I updated the code, please have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/diogocosta/u8w7s49v/4/

Answer (score 0):

That’s because `document.getElementById(fruits[i].id)` is looking for HTML elements that don’t exist.

You need to create two more `p` elements and assign them ids `0`, `1`, and `2`. Like this:

```
<p id=“0”></p>
<p id=”1”></p>
<p id=“2”></p>
```

before your `<script>` tag.

**Edit:** Also, `fruits[i].quantity + fruits[i].kind` will return an error because `fruits[i].quantity` is a Number, while `fruits[i].kind` is a String. You can’t concatenate a Number to a String directly by using the `+` operator in JavaScript.

Instead, use:

```
fruits[i].quantity.toString() + fruits[i].kind
```

See docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString

BR,

Comment: Actually, he doesn't need to create more `p` elements with ids. He can do it on demand, by iterating through the list and creating a new DOM element.

Comment: @DiogoLessa yeah, that's right. Here's the docs for that: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2
And greetings from Rio!